# String array is not reading in the value?

Tags: c

In the Second while loop the data in string is there i checked "data added" however when i stepin and check what string[walker + *len] it constantly has NUL ('\0') even after len is increment? What is the error here ?!?

```
char* getWord(char* string, short* len)
{
 size_t walker = 0;

  /*POINT TO THE FIRST CHAR*/
  while (string[walker] == ' ' || string[walker] == '\0')
   ++walker;


 while ( string[walker + *len] != ' ' || string[walker + *len] != '\0'  )
   ++(*len);

 return (&string[walker]);
```

Comment: we need more code, how do you call your function? also, you could simply do `return string+walker;`

Comment: The problem in your code lies in the implicit contract between the caller and callee, specifically, who is reponsible for initializing `*len`? Since you didn't provide the caller's code, we are forced to guess what is going on. To avoid this sort of guessing, please provide a minimal, complete, compilable sample program. For more information about how to produce such a program, and their benefits, consult http://sscce.org/.

Comment: The first loop is broken if you pass a string like `" "` because it will read beyond the end of the string until it finds a non-blank non-null byte. This is unlikely to be what you intended. In the second loop, you have no idea what value is in `*len`, so you don't know if it is safe to index with `walker + *len`. Maybe you intended to set `*len = 0;` before the second loop. The second loop condition is also broken; if `string[walker+*len] == ' '` then the second condition will be true; otherwise the first is, so your code should crash. Be careful with `||` vs `&&` and negated conditions.

Answer (score 1):

You have a few logic bugs there - it should be something like this:

```
char* getWord(char* string, short* len)
{
  size_t walker = 0;
  *len = 0; // << initialisation of *len

  /*POINT TO THE FIRST CHAR*/
  while (string[walker] == ' ') // << remove incorrect check for end of string
    ++walker;

  while (string[walker + *len] != ' ' && string[walker + *len] != '\0') // << fix logic for testing for space or end of string
    ++(*len);

  return &string[walker];
}
```

Comment: Perhaps isalpha instead of the second while loop?(or isalnum)

Comment: @Ethan: yes, that would be more robust - I tried to keep the changes to a minimum to avoid information overload, so I just fixed the definite bugs. There's still plenty of room for improvement of course.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that `*len` is 0 when you call your function? Don't you need to initialize it? Also, in the second while condition I'd guess that you want to use a `&&` rather than `||`.